# How can I show timerformat in timer (minutes seconds) WPF vb.net

Tags: wpf, vb.net, windows, web, timer

I have a timer and I want to display the minutes and seconds. my timer goes up, and when there are 60 seconds, there should be a minute, and seconds must be nulled. Now it simply counts the in seconds. I hope for your help.

```
Private timer As DispatcherTimer
Private CountUp As Integer

Public Sub DispatcherTimerSetup()

    timer = New DispatcherTimer()
    timer.Interval = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)
    AddHandler timer.Tick, AddressOf timer_Tick
    timer.Start()

End Sub

Private Sub timer_Tick(sender As Object, e As Object)

    CountUp += 1
    txblCountdown.Text = CountUp.ToString("00\:00")
    'timeformat

End Sub
```

best regards,
Polina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a TimeSpan to do this.

```
Private Sub timer_Tick(sender As Object, e As Object)

    CountUp += 1
    Dim counter As TimeSpan
    counter = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(CountUp)
    txblCountdown.Text = counter.ToString("mm\:ss")

End Sub
```